# When is it ok to pass integer to function needing unsigned vice versa

Tags: c

I can't find a link now but passing `int` to function which needs `unsigned type` should be ok as long as the `int` is positive right? (and falls in range of unsigned); I got a warning that's why I am asking

assuming no casts

vice versa should also be ok assuming `unsigned integers` value fits in `int` range?

Comment: What warning you get? Can you post your code?

Comment: it is a warning from some tool about losing sign

Comment: "some tool"?  What tool? Do you mean the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a signed integer to a function expecting an unsigned integer has well-defined behavior.  If the argument value is within the range of the parameter type, there's a trivial conversion; the value remains the same. If the argument value is outside that range, it will be converted, effectively by discarding the high-order bits.

This is ok if and only if that behavior is consistent with the way your application needs to behave.

Passing an unsigned integer to a function expecting a signed integer has well-defined behavior *if* the value is within the range of the parameter type.  If it isn't, then the implicit conversion will yield an implementation-defined result (or, in principle, it can raise an implementation-defined signal, but I don't know of any implementations that do that). Typically the result is equivalent to discarding the high-order bits, or interpreting the unsigned value as if it were a signed value (treating the high-order bit as a sign bit), but that's not guaranteed by the language. For unsigned-to-signed conversions, it's best to ensure that the value is within the range of the target type.

Very often (but not always) a conversion like this is an indication that the argument should have been of the same type as the parameter in the first place.

This all assumes that the function is properly declared with a prototype, so the compiler knows, when it sees the call, what type the function expects.  If there is no prototype, or if the function is variadic (like `printf`), then you need to be more careful.  There is no conversion, but you can rely on `int` and `unsigned int` being interchangeable *for values within the range of both*. (But it's not a great idea to depend on that; it's best to ensure that the argument you pass is of the expected type.)

Comment: basically you agreed with what I typed? (no casts too)

Comment: passing negative int is probably not good idea to function needing unsigned

Comment: @user70012: Yes, assuming the argument value is within the range of the parameter type there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken down into two different questions:

> Will it work?

Yes, probably. All variable values are just sequences of bits, and you can, to some degree, play fast and loose with types and still get a correct result if you're careful.

> Should I do it?

No, for several reasons:

1. You shouldn't get in the habit of ignoring warnings. They are there for a reason: they let you know that results may not be what you expect. You should put as much effort into correctly resolving them as you would an error.
2. Your code will be harder to understand to future readers. You should try to make your code as understandable and maintainable to future readers (including yourself) as possible.  Part of this is using the correct types. If you need to use a function that expects a certain type and you have to give it data of a different type for some reason, you should cast it to make your intentions clear.
3. It is hard enough to understand and debug code. You're only making it harder on yourself when you make implicit assumptions in your code. Try to refactor it to use the types that are required for the operations you want to do. Your current assumption is that your value will *always* be positive, and *always* be within the range of a signed integer. If either of these conditions are violated (which you should assume is possible, since no code is perfect), then you will have unexpected behavior from your code. You should add some checks for these conditions before using the value where an unsigned int is expected, then explicitly cast it. This will make debugging easier by catching errors, *and* make your intentions clear to future readers.

Comment: If the int is positive and same or lower rank than the unsigned, it is not broken, but well-defined. You do that likely anytime you pas an int-literal without trailing `U` to an unsigned.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not trying to suggest that anything is broken, just that for the benefit of future maintainers and debugging, casts should be made obvious and some checks should be put in place to guard against erroneous conditions.

Answer (score 0):

That's right.  It's up to you to determine if your app is safe this way, and that's all the compiler is warning you about.  As long as the value stays in the range you expect, no surprises will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Both directions are ok, as long as the *current* value of the source fits into the *allowed* range of the destination. Some tools or compilers (gcc: `-Wconversion`) still warn about this for a good reason: to get your attention.

If you are absolutely sure the value fits, just use a cast to suppress the warning. But add a comment to that line (or before it) why you use that cast actually. Some editors will highlight special keyword in comments (e.g. `// NOTE:`), so you will see there is something to be aware of.

**Once the value does not fit, you exhibit *undefined bahaviour*, so be aware!.**

Comment: didn't use cast though :)

Comment: You should use the cast with caution, but use it, to not get confused by the warning. There are some casts you cannot avoid.

Comment: I meant my program is still well defined even without cast in this case

Comment: Yes, but the cast is just for the comment (did I not state that clear enough?). For that tool, you might not want it, but I compile with all(most) all warnings enabled - which I generally strongly recommend. So I would get that warning every time I rebuild. And unnecessary warnings might make others to be overlooked.